# the use of definitive article before possessive

Tags: definite-article

should we use "the" in the following sentences?

we should consider "**the**" teachers' perceptions in our research. by considering "**the**" teachers' perspectives we can understand their cognition.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the definite article when the subject is defined. So, are you speaking about *all teachers* in general, or are you talking about a *specific group of teachers*?

- "We should consider teachers' perceptions" would refer to the perceptions of *all* teachers.
- "We should consider *the* teachers' perceptions" would refer to a specific group of teachers that you have previously referred to, or are under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The articles may be added or omitted and most English speakers will understand.

Comment: As the other answer suggests they are not interchangeable. Can you edit to explain why you disagree?

Comment: They are interchangeable in casual speech with no significant loss in understanding. Context provides these various shades of meaning, not the dictionary.